# Deleting tmp files

Tags: r, temporary-files

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296377/automatically-delete-files-folders-in-r) post on how to delete tmp files. The solution in that post is:

```
do.call(file.remove, list(list.files("C:/Temp", full.names = TRUE)))
```

The directory "C:/Temp" is presumably fine with windows machines. Since I'm on linux I wasn't sure what my tmp file dir was so I did this:

```
tmp <- tempfile()
```

Which returns: "/tmp/RtmpNS80no/file147c37e54e8e"

So, I tried this:

```
do.call(file.remove, list(list.files("tmp", full.names = TRUE)))
```

This returns "logical(0)" so presumably did not work?

How do I delete all my tmp files?

Comment: What does `list.files("tmp", full.names = TRUE)` give?

Comment: The directory location in `list.files` is relative to your current working directory, so you either need to spell it out in full or make sure you are in the directory above `tmp`.  Perhaps you also need `recursive=TRUE` in your `list.files` call.

Comment: `tempfile()` gives you a file path for a temporary file in your temp file directory. The temp directory location for your R session is found with `tempdir()`. the temp directory can be compute with `basename(tempdir())`

Comment: it is `dirname(tempdir())` not `basename`. sorry

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get the temp directory for the current R session. It does not change when called several times

```r
tmp_dir <- tempdir()
tmp_dir
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh"
tempdir()
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh"
```

The temp directory contains the temp files and directory for the current
R session

```r
list.files(tmp_dir)
#> [1] "file16dc20539ab"  "file16dc4ad71f"   "file16dc5bab1716"
#> [4] "file16dc74d65663"
```

The session temp directory is in the temp directory of the system. You can use this path if you want to delete all in the temp directory of the system (not recommended though because it is for all the system, not just R temp files)

```r
dirname(tmp_dir)
#> [1] "C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Temp"
```

This path is also contains in an environnement variable for the OS. (Obviously, I am on windows)

```r
Sys.getenv("TEMP")
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
shell("echo %TMP%", intern = T) # command line from R on windows
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
```

`tempfile()` gives the path of a possible temporary file, in the
`tempdir()` directory by default, with no file extension. The file is
not created and `tempfile` gives different values when calls several
times

```r
tmp_file <- tempfile()
tmp_file
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh\\file16dc202636f"
file.exists(tmp_file)
#> [1] FALSE

tempfile() # new file path when called again
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh\\file16dc72594e58"
```

We can write something to tmp_file.

```r
# file is created by writeLines if it does not exist (this is the case here)
writeLines("This is a temp file", con = tmp_file)
file.exists(tmp_file)
#> [1] TRUE
```

We can read from this file

```r
readLines(tmp_file)
#> [1] "This is a temp file"
```

Now if you want to delete this file

```r
file.remove(tmp_file)
#> [1] TRUE
file.exists(tmp_file)
#> [1] FALSE
```

If you want to delete all files in the R session temp folder, you can use
`file.remove` on a list of files. For this example purpose, I deleted all
temp file beginning with "file" (`"^file"` is a regex for that pattern). There are more than I created - R session seems to create some temp file along the way.

```r
files <- list.files(tmp_dir, full.names = T, pattern = "^file")
files
#>  [1] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc1a6a6e15"
#>  [2] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc1ff572fc"
#>  [3] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc20539ab" 
#>  [4] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc2e2227b8"
#>  [5] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc4ad71f"  
#>  [6] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc513c35b6"
#>  [7] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc570a473f"
#>  [8] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc5bab1716"
#>  [9] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc6e102bd4"
#> [10] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc6f253f90"
#> [11] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc74d65663"
file.remove(files)
#> Warning in file.remove(files): impossible d'effacer le fichier 'C:
#> \Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmusYkh/file16dc1ff572fc', Ã  cause de
#> 'Permission denied'
#>  [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I get a warning because there is a file I can't delete (probably in use by R right now)

If you want to remove a folder you can use `unlink` too

```r
# create a new directory under tempdir
dir.create(dir1 <- file.path(tempdir(), "testdir"))
# create 2 file under this new directory
file.create(file1 <- tempfile(tmpdir = dir1))
#> [1] TRUE
file.create(file2 <- tempfile(tmpdir = dir1))
#> [1] TRUE
file1
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/testdir\\file16dc26b5cb7"
file2
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/testdir\\file16dc2b0816fe"
list.files(dir1, full.names = T)
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/testdir/file16dc26b5cb7" 
#> [2] "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpmusYkh/testdir/file16dc2b0816fe"

# we can delete the all directory with `unlink`. It deletes also the directory
unlink(dir1, recursive = T)
dir.exists(dir1)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Comment: This is great. Just be careful not to do `unlink(tempdir())` which will clear all temporary files for you current R session and make bad things happen.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple way

```
unlink(paste0(normalizePath(tempdir()), "/", dir(tempdir())), recursive = TRUE)
```

To confirm it worked

```
dir(tempdir())
# character(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

After spending hours to find out *how to use cmd to delete old files and folders* I ended up writing this R script which I will definitely automate to run every week:

```
#Windows Environmental variable %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
PCTempDir <- Sys.getenv("TEMP")

#detect and delete folders with pattern "Rtmp"
folders <- dir(PCTempDir, pattern = "Rtmp", full.names = TRUE)
unlink(folders, recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE, expand = TRUE)
```

This will delete `Rtmp*` folders with files left by executed R scripts as I have a lot of them on my computer

Of course such script could be also expanded to accommodate other folders

Answer (score 1):

The accepted [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45894750/1851270)
assumes a unique temp dir.
However, several packages might run their task using specific temp directories. A typical behaviour (see for example [devtools](https://devtools.r-lib.org/)) is to clean up clutter, when the task is successfully completed, but to leave the temp material, in case of errors, to allow the user to check for log files and the likes.  When you happen to deal with them, your hard disk gets full of microtemp dirs, and removing them manually is impractical.

```
tdirs <- Sys.glob(file.path(dirname(tempdir()), "Rtmp*"))
print(tdirs)  # Perhaps check before deleting 
names(which(sapply(tdirs[! tdirs %in% tempdir()], unlink, recursive = TRUE) != 0))
```

Above, I use the parent of `tempdir()` and the `Rtmp` prefix to identify the location of temporary directories.
Last line returns the directories that it was not possible to remove (most likely locked by the OS).
`[! tdirs %in% tempdir()]` leaves the main session directory, to avoid restarting R.
Tested on Linux.