# pdf_text function not releasing ram (on windows)

Tags: r, pdftools

`pdf_text()` is not releasing RAM. Each time the function runs, it uses more RAM, and doesn't free it up until the R session is terminated. I am on windows.

#### Minimal example

```
# This takes ~60 seconds and uses ~500mb of RAM, which is then unavailable for other processes

library(pdftools)
for (i in 1:5) {
  
  print(i)
  pdf_text("https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/spatstat.pdf")
  
}
```

#### My question

Why is `pdf_text()` using so much memory and how can it be freed it up? (without having to terminate the R session)

#### What I've tried so far

I have tried `gc()` inside the loop

I have checked that `pdf_text()` isn't creating some hidden objects (by inspecting `ls(all=TRUE)`

I have [cleared the R session's temp files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56715074/5783745)

#### Also note

Although the size of the particular pdf in the example above is about 5mb, calling `pdf_text` on it uses about 20 times that much ram! I am not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a memory leak. However I cannot reproduce this problem on MacOS.

I have [started an issue](https://github.com/ropensci/pdftools/issues/64) to track this, can you please report which version of pdftools and libpoppler you are using that show this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone arriving here through google, here's what solves the issue for me - it's built on Jeroen's suggestion [here](https://github.com/ropensci/pdftools/issues/64#issuecomment-504731500)

```
pdf_urls <- c("https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf", 
              "https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf",
              "https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdftools/pdftools.pdf")

pdfs <- list()

for(i in 1:length(pdf_urls)) {

  print(paste("Obtaining pdf", i, "of", length(pdf_urls)))
  pdf_url <- pdf_urls[i]

  pdfs[[i]] <- callr::r(function(pdf_path){
    pdftools::pdf_text(pdf_path)
  }, args = list(pdf_url))

}
```