# What happens to tempfiles created with tempfile() in R?

Tags: r, temporary-files

I'm using `tempfile()` within a function in a package, so users will be creating new files. I do not want to leave a mess behind.

Does R automatically delete files created in the directory accessed with `tempfile()`, or must these be deleted manually?

If files are automatically removed, on what basis does this occur (e.g. end of R session, after closing RStudio, after some time interval, or something else?)

Obviously it's not hard to delete them with some extra code (related post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56715074/680068), but I will avoid that if they are automatically taken care of with some existing process.

Comment: I can’t believe that this isn‘t clearly stated in the documentation. But I can’t find it there.

Comment: @jay.sf That question doesn’t answer this one.

Comment: maybe its in a `.Last.sys` function: from `?quit`: `There is a system analogue, .Last.sys(), which is run after .Last() if runLast is true.`

Comment: an unanswered rstudio server qn: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-server-doesnt-delete-rtmp-folders/37648

Comment: I do know that all files placed in the (default) `tempdir()` will be cleaned up, along with the directory when the R session is closed normally. A crash will not clean this directory up. So if your R sessions are prone to crashing, you might want to  clean the files up with unlink, otherwise R should clean up the files. Of course if the files are large you might want to do the cleaning yourself anyway as soon as they are not needed anymore.

Comment: @phiver Sure — but where is this documented?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, it is not in the official documentation. I only know this due to the use in the quantmod package and debugging some functions that download data into the tempdir, but the closest I can find to any explanation is [this blogpost](http://rstat.consulting/blog/temporary-dir-and-files-in-r/).

Comment: this is a shot in the dark, but because it is in a function can you wrap your code in `local()` to evaluate locally ? I am not sure if this would work when creating files - but it does work when creating variables in R.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

(All this assumes you are using the default argument for `tmpdir` and the `TEMP` environment variable is set normally for your operating system.)

**tl;dr Temporary files are deleted whenever `R_CleanTempDir` runs (as when the R session terminates)**

The temporary files are deleted by deleting the temporary directory `tempdir()`. This occurs via the internal function [`R_CleanTempDir`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/06185bd431beb9b6e0883193273d1779ef2c6a2c/src/unix/sys-std.c#L1159) (link points to a unix implementation). This can be invoked through a variety of instances, but the most usual case is via `quit` (see below for the full chain). To answer your question, the temporary files will be deleted under a "normal" quit of the R session. (The "normal" is there to avoid things like a power failure at an inopportune time, plus "suicides".)

Indeed this is mentioned in the helpfile for `?quit`:

> Exactly what happens at termination of an R session depends on the platform and GUI interface in use. A typical sequence is to run .Last() and .Last.sys() (unless runLast is false), to save the workspace if requested (and in most cases also to save the session history: see savehistory), then run any finalizers (see reg.finalizer) that have been set to be run on exit, close all open graphics devices, **remove the session temporary directory** and print any remaining warnings (e.g., from .Last() and device closure).

As suggested in that helpfile, you may want to see if `reg.finalizer` would be helpful for your issue.

In some circumstances [`tempdir()` may be deleted during long-running R session](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/tempdir-may-be-deleted-during-long-running-R-session-td4732832.html), but to guarantee deletion of temporary files you must explicitly remove them in the session or quit the session.

---

**`do_quit`**

```c
SEXP attribute_hidden do_quit(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP rho)
{
    const char *tmp;
    SA_TYPE ask=SA_DEFAULT;
    int status, runLast;

    checkArity(op, args);
    /* if there are any browser contexts active don't quit */
    if(countContexts(CTXT_BROWSER, 1)) {
    warning(_("cannot quit from browser"));
    return R_NilValue;
    }
    if( !isString(CAR(args)) )
    error(_("one of \"yes\", \"no\", \"ask\" or \"default\" expected."));
    tmp = CHAR(STRING_ELT(CAR(args), 0)); /* ASCII */
    if( !strcmp(tmp, "ask") ) {
    ask = SA_SAVEASK;
    if(!R_Interactive)
        warning(_("save=\"ask\" in non-interactive use: command-line default will be used"));
    } else if( !strcmp(tmp, "no") )
    ask = SA_NOSAVE;
    else if( !strcmp(tmp, "yes") )
    ask = SA_SAVE;
    else if( !strcmp(tmp, "default") )
    ask = SA_DEFAULT;
    else
    error(_("unrecognized value of 'save'"));
    status = asInteger(CADR(args));
    if (status == NA_INTEGER) {
    warning(_("invalid 'status', 0 assumed"));
    status = 0;
    }
    runLast = asLogical(CADDR(args));
    if (runLast == NA_LOGICAL) {
    warning(_("invalid 'runLast', FALSE assumed"));
    runLast = 0;
    }
    /* run the .Last function. If it gives an error, will drop back to main
       loop. */
    R_CleanUp(ask, status, runLast);
    exit(0);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}
```

invokes **`R_CleanUp`** which invokes **`R_CleanTempDir`**:

```c
void R_CleanUp(SA_TYPE saveact, int status, int runLast)
{
    if(saveact == SA_DEFAULT) /* The normal case apart from R_Suicide */
    saveact = SaveAction;

    if(saveact == SA_SAVEASK) {
    if(R_Interactive) {
        switch (R_YesNoCancel(G_("Save workspace image?"))) {
        case YES:
        saveact = SA_SAVE;
        break;
        case NO:
        saveact = SA_NOSAVE;
        break;
        case CANCEL:
        // There might be residual events with destroyed handles
        R_ProcessEvents();
        jump_to_toplevel();
        break;

        }
    } else saveact = SaveAction;
    }

    switch (saveact) {
    case SA_SAVE:
    if(runLast) R_dot_Last();
    if(R_DirtyImage) R_SaveGlobalEnv();
    if (CharacterMode == RGui) {
        R_setupHistory(); /* re-read the history size and filename */
        wgl_savehistory(R_HistoryFile, R_HistorySize);
    } else if(R_Interactive && CharacterMode == RTerm) {
        R_setupHistory(); /* re-read the history size and filename */
        gl_savehistory(R_HistoryFile, R_HistorySize);
    }
    break;
    case SA_NOSAVE:
    if(runLast) R_dot_Last();
    break;
    case SA_SUICIDE:
    default:
    break;
    }
    R_RunExitFinalizers();
    editorcleanall();
    CleanEd();
    KillAllDevices(); /* Unix does not do this under SA_SUICIDE */
    AllDevicesKilled = TRUE; /* used in devWindows.c to inhibit callbacks */
    R_CleanTempDir(); /* changes directory */
    if (R_Interactive && CharacterMode == RTerm)
    SetConsoleTitle(oldtitle);
    if (R_CollectWarnings && saveact != SA_SUICIDE
    && CharacterMode == RTerm)   /* no point in doing this for Rgui
                    as the console is about to close */
    PrintWarnings();        /* from device close and (if run) .Last */
    app_cleanup();
    RConsole = NULL;
    // Add some protection against calling this more than once:
    // caused by signals on Unix, so maybe cannot happen here.
    if(ifp) { 
    fclose(ifp);    /* input file from -f or --file= */
    ifp = NULL; 
    }
    if(ifile[0]) {
    unlink(ifile); /* input file from -e */
    ifile[0] = '\0';
    }
    exit(status);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, the function uses the temp directory returned by `tempdir()` which returns a path to the system temp directory. So it is controlled by the OS. If you use a different directory, I guess you will have to clean it yourself.