# How to access the NetCDF file returned by an API call?

Tags: r, netcdf, httr

I have this API request: https://dataset.api.hub.geosphere.at/v1/grid/historical/inca-v1-1h-1km?parameters=RR&parameters=T2M&parameters=UU&parameters=VV&parameters=RH2M&start=2014-01-01&end=2014-02-01&bbox=47.25392576%2C11.34458542%2C47.278834%2C11.44352138&output_format=netcdf&filename=file_try

I use this code to get the data in R:

```
link <- "https://dataset.api.hub.geosphere.at/v1/grid/historical/inca-v1-1h-1km?parameters=RR&parameters=T2M&parameters=UU&parameters=VV&parameters=RH2M&start=2014-01-01&end=2014-02-01&bbox=47.25392576%2C11.34458542%2C47.278834%2C11.44352138&output_format=netcdf&filename=file_try"

data <- httr::GET(link) %>% 
    httr::content()
```

My problem is to obtain the NetCDF file. In the API documentation it says: content-type: application/x-netcdf. Until now I receive a object of format "raw". I guess the solution lies in the content() function, but I don't know what to specify here. I think NetCDF files are never safe as R objects but instead accessed from the hard drive, that's why this doesn't work.

Would be calling download.file(link) a better option? The problem here is that the downloaded file is not recognized by ncdf4 (Error in R_nc4_open: NETCDF: Unknown file format). To me it seems that the file has a 'double' file name, because I specify the filename in the API request (at the very end) and additionally in download.file(destfile=...).
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can (if you want a [temporary download only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095164/what-happens-to-tempfiles-created-with-tempfile-in-r)) do this:

```
the_tempfile <- tempfile() ## create a temporary file

download.file(link,
              destfile = the_tempfile,
              mode = "wb" ## save as BINARY
              )
```

inspect (using, e.g. {ncdf4})

```
library(ncdf4)

nc_open(the_tempfile)
```

Comment: this do not work: Error in nc_open(the_tempfile) : 
  Error in nc_open trying to open file C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi07Rb7\file33e4358125dd (return_on_error= FALSE )